# Google cloud sdk environment variables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to set the project id in environment variable so that I don't want to write again and again

kindly help me how to do in google cloud SDK

when i use this command "export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=$(gcloud config get-value core/project)"

it gives me error
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Where do you use this command?

Answer (score 1):

See @saigeetha-sundar correct reply.

However, it appears that you have set the Project ID using `gcloud config set core/project`. The intent of the `gcloud config set` command is to set default values for `gcloud` properties so that you do not need to write them repeatedly (as you wish).

Just to be clear:

If the `core/project` value is unset...

```
gcloud config unset core/project
```

If you don't specify `--project=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]` on commands that expect it, you'll get errors...

> **NOTE** I'm using `gcloud iam service-accounts list` as an example.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
ERROR: The required property [project] is not currently set.
You may set it for your current workspace by running:

  $ gcloud config set project VALUE

or it can be set temporarily by the environment variable [CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT]
```

And you must always specify it, e.g.:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
DISPLAY NAME                     EMAIL
Default compute service account  1234567890123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

But, if you set the configuration value:

```
gcloud config set core/project [[YOUR-PROJECT]]
```

Then any command that requires the project value will work without specifying it:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
DISPLAY NAME                     EMAIL
Default compute service account  1234567890123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute a Linux command on Windows.

The equivalent for Windows executed from a batch file is:

```
gcloud config get-value core/project > project.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%x in (project.tmp) do set GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=%%x
del project.tmp
```

Put those lines in a batch file (*.bat). The reason is the `%%` escaping. If you hand type into the Command Prompt use the following example. Notice the change from `%%` to `%`.

The equivalent for Windows typed at a Comman Prompt:

```
gcloud config get-value core/project > project.tmp
for /f "delims=" %x in (project.tmp) do set GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=%x
del project.tmp
```

The command `gcloud config get-value core/project` outputs more than one line of text. This is the reason for the `for` loop. The for loop will read each line from `project.tmp` and assign the value to GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT. The last set value is the PROJECT ID.

If you use this example in a batch script, then add the keyword `call` in front of `gcloud`. The reason is that `gcloud` is a script itself and when it returns without the `call`, your script will exit.

```
call gcloud config get-value core/project > project.tmp
```

Windows legacy (antique) syntax can be a pain at times.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the command from my project, the command is running successfully in Google Cloud shell, but the error seems to be Windows command line error, if you are using windows to run the command you would have to ,use the "Set" command to create variables.